# Celery and fanout - ensuring unique queue per worker?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to do something in celery that should be fairly simple, but can't see an obvious configuration for.

I've got a master host and a number of slave hosts. The master host runs a Django application that sometimes has to instruct the slaves to do things asynchronously. The task needs to be carried out by all the slaves, and there is no return type.

Celery appears to be an obvious choice. My knowledge of RabbitMQ tells me that I should have a scenario where a single `fanout` exchange should exist on rMQ and each celery worker should create an exclusive queue and bind to this exchange. Then, every task request published by the master will be queued into each worker and then executed by every slave.

However, looking through all the celery docs, they seem geared around the scenario where each worker carrying out the same task binds to the same queue. This won't work with a `fanout` exchange type, as `fanout` simply creates one message per connected queue.

If I was using `pika` and pure python, I'd simply call something like `channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)` and then bind that to my exchange, ensuring that each client has its own queue and gets a copy of the message.

How do you do this in celery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is short, as I'm on my phone.  See the celery docs -> Userguide -> Routing.  You want the `Broadcast` entity in Kombu which do  what you describe, and there's a section about it in the routing guide.